# Does using an image for a send button, or span tags to style each letter, confuse visitors with disabilities?

Tags: html, button, input, accessibility

I am styling the send buttons on my contact form and blog subscription signup. Each letter of the word SEND is a different color. I can use an image for this or, thanks to help I received in another thread here, I can use button instead of input and style each letter with span and nth-of-type tags.

But I'm unclear on how this might affect accessibility. I want to make it clear that this is a send button to submit their contact form content or email address for the subscription.

Does anyone know how this renders per accessibility concerns?

Comment: I think this might be a better question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic - agree with previous commenter.

Comment: On-topic, IMO; the issue of whether to color each letter or not in the first place is UX, but whether to use BUTTON / SPAN / IMG tags and/or CSS or some combination is an implementation issue that can have accessibility impact given that screenreaders may treat them differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`button` is the right element for this case (ideally with role="submit" on it as well). Coloring every letter differently does seem like an iffy UX call; this is a utility button, so it definitely needs to be clear and easy to read.

Speaking of accessibility, be aware that:

- some screen readers (assistive technology) will pause at all HTML tags, including inline spans.
- if you write your button like this:

  ```
  <button>SEND</button>
  ```

  screen-readers will pronounce it as "S-E-N-D" - one letter at a time, like an acronym. You can avoid this with a little CSS.

  HTML:

  ```
  <button>Send</button>
  ```

  CSS:

  ```
  button { text-transform: uppercase; }
  ```

Comment: Thank you. This is why I decided to use an image. I'm glad you mentioned it here as a good reminder. Another example: I love drop caps, but if you use span tags, it isolates the first letter, which is why p:first-child seems to be the better option.

Comment: You can put an image inside the button, with an appropriate alt attribute. While you can use a CSS background-image to style your button, it will disappear if the user is in high-contrast mode.

Comment: `screen-readers will pronounce it as "S-E-N-D"` - @jack, can you give an example screenreader that does this? Current screenreaders such as VoiceOver/JAWS/NVDA read this out as "Send" regardless of casing; I'm wondering if this advice is based on experience or 2nd hand advice?

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are always good because they look clickable. It is good that users are able to figure out things.

Do not use more colors than necessary. Colors are used to seek for attention, if you abuse of them then nothing really gets the attention.

The best combination are buttons are icons with words. The first thing that captures the attention are icons and the must follow the "standards" (envelope for mail, house for home link...), the same with colors. Red wrong, green ok...

About accessibility is more the attributes that you put in the html so readers can use it, or voice translators... For example images should have an "alt" tag, descriptions...

If the html is clean and follows the standards you are already doing an accessible web.

http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/accessibility.php

I recommend (and many people do) the book "Don't make me thing" by Steve Krug (I know it's out of the scope of the question).

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular implication on accessibility, except that letters in different colors may pose an unnecessary cognitive challenge: the user may ask himself what the colors mean. But the odds are that this is not a problem. It’s more like a style issue; it may look childish.

When letters are wrapped in `span` elements, it is possible that some browsers have difficulties in recognizing the sequence as a single word. But this is a remote possibility, and such browsers would represent inferior technology and would have problems with many pages.

Compared with an image, there is not much difference in accessibility, if the image is an image submit button with an adequate `alt` attribute. It’s a different issue if you use just an `img` element with action associated with it using JavaScript; then you would need to care about accessibility attributes, and the page would not work without JavaScript (probably for no good reason).